# How can I use a buildpack on Heroku that runs more than 15 mins?

Tags: heroku

I tried using `COMPILE_TIMEOUT: 6000` and even set `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile` but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that no, you can't. At least I didn't find any evidence that it is possible.

The longer answer is that the Heroku way of doing it is by saving precompiled packages online and fetching them during the buildpack execution. To build binaries in dyno environment one should use [vulcan](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries). A good example of such usage can be found [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/tree/master/support), notice the two compilation scripts under *support* folder.

Answer (score 1):

As far I can know, you cannot exceed the documented [15 minute limitation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#slug-compilation).